# Retrieve port name for excel.ActivePrinter

Tags: c#, excel, printing, wmi, wmi-query

Hi for the print method to work on excel i need the printername and the port name like this:
"printer On NE3" just as an example. The problem is, is that I use a virtual printer and the port is different, pretty much every time i need to use it.

The program needs to run in the background, so open dialog boxes to choose is not an option.
I have also tried to retrieve the port name from WMI with this:

```
    protected string FindPrinterWithPort(string printerName)
    {
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        query.Append("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer ");
        query.Append("WHERE DeviceID = \""+printerName+"\"");
        ObjectQuery objectQuery = new ObjectQuery(query.ToString());
        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(objectQuery);
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
        {
            return printerName +" On "+ mo["PortName"];
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

The portname i receive doing this gives me the full path to the virtual printer program.
I previously used the methods below to change printer for excel, and i alway knew they should be changed eventually, the code is neither fast nor good, but it worked for a while, until I made it multi-threaded and its just a big blockade. Because i need to lock these methods not to change the default printer in windows.

```
    private bool SetPrinterForExcel(string printerName){
        string[] ports = new string[]{"Ne00:", "Ne01:", "Ne02:", "Ne03:", "Ne04:",
            "Ne05:", "Ne06:", "Ne07:", "Ne08:", 
               "Ne09:", "Ne10:", "Ne11:", "Ne12:", 
               "Ne13:", "Ne14:", "Ne15:", "Ne16:", 
               "LPT1:", "LPT2:", "File:", "SMC100:"};
        foreach (string port in ports)
        {
            string printerWithPort = printerName + " On " + port;
            bool success = SetAndTestPrinter(printerWithPort);
            if(success)
                return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
    private bool SetAndTestPrinter(string printerWithPort)
    {
        try
        {
            excel.ActivePrinter = printerWithPort;
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Any Idea how to retrieve the port, or is there a way from WMI query i can get the correct port.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

I have not gotten it work getting, what i have done to print now is change the default printer on windows and then just do the print method on my excel object. I Changed it by using:

```
    [DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool SetDefaultPrinter(string Name);
```

And i lock it method and print. I have thought about trying to do a lock and save the ActivePrinter, even tho i believe performance will properly just as bad. Because the lock will stay until the default printer is changed, which takes sometimes up to 1 second, in a multi-threaded envirorment thats is a very long lock.

```
 string printernamewithPort = string.Empty;
 lock (ActivePrinterLock)
 {
    SetDefaultPrinter(printername);
    printernamewithPort = excel.ActivePrinter;
 }
 foreach (Worksheet worksheet in workbook.Worksheets)
 {
    worksheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = XlPaperSize.xlPaperA4;
    worksheet.PageSetup.Orientation = XlPageOrientation.xlPortrait;
    worksheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1;

    worksheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = false;
    worksheet.PrintOutEx(ActivePrinter: printernamewithPort,Collate: true, Preview: false, PrintToFile: false);
 }
```

What i dunno is that, if the default printer changes right away from another thread, if it looses the port given to the virtual printer. I have not done proper testing of this. In normal circumstances it seems that my Method FindPrinterWithPort would work.

Comment: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices here i could use search for the name of the printer, and read the port from the registry that is the solution

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar problem in vba and this worked for me, maybe you can leverage something similar?

[Setting Default Printer Through VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58929416/setting-default-printer-through-vba)

```
CreateObject(WScript.Network).SetDefaultPrinter "RecOffice_Pink"
```

Where "RecOffice_Pink" does not need to inlcude the port!