# How to set PowerPoint.PrintOptions?

Tags: c#, printing, powerpoint

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
    
Application ppt = new Application();
Presentation doc = ppt.Presentations.Open(file);
ppt.Activate();

PrintOptions printOptions = doc.PrintOptions;
printOptions.ActivePrinter = "Adobe PDF";
doc.PrintOut();
ppt.Quit();
```

But [`PrintOptions.ActivePrinter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.printoptions.activeprinter) is read only...

How do I set the selected printer?

Answer (score -1):

You can't, unfortunately.

In [a now-removed Microsoft KB article Q166818](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php?title=Microsoft_KB_Archive/166818), originally dating back to 1997 and last updated in 2006, Microsoft documents that PowerPoint's active printer device cannot be changed via COM Automation nor by VBA:

> The `ActivePrinter` property is read-only in the PowerPoint object library and cannot be changed programmatically.

Unfortunately I don't know *why* this is the case, and it seems such an obvious thing to include. I did try to speculate some reasons, but I can't think of a reasonable excuse for why Word, Excel, and even Access let VBA/COM change the current `Application.Printer` but PowerPoint doesn't, especially not after over 20 years of continuous development. But I do note that PowerPoint's support for VBA and COM automation is lacking *overall* compared to other Office programs, for example there's no Macro Recorder feature - so maybe it just wasn't a development priority and not enough people threatened to *not* buy the next version of PowerPoint until this specific feature was added - such is how software development works.

---

BTW, the `Presentation.PrintOptions` property exposes the print-options **saved** into the `.ppt`/`.pptx` file, which presumably will be those of the computer that the presentation was authored and last-saved on, rather than print settings appropriate for the current computer's printer.

A possible workaround might exist [if you first set the Windows's default printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971604/how-do-i-set-the-windows-default-printer-in-c) (or in [VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58929416/setting-default-printer-through-vba)), and then just call the `PrintOut()` method and *hope* that the correct printer is used.

Something like this (**I have not tested this code, I don't know if it works or not)**:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/setdefaultprinter
    [DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SetDefaultPrinter(string name);
}

public static class MyProgram
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        Application ppt = new Application();
        Presentation doc = ppt.Presentations.Open(file);
        ppt.Activate();

        if( !NativeMethods.SetDefaultPrinter("Adobe PDF") )
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException( "Couldn't set default printer." );
        }

        doc.PrintOut();
        ppt.Quit();
    }
}
```